# How would you evaluate the series: $\arccos(1)-\arccos(1/2)+\arccos(1/3)-\arccos(1/4)+\arccos(1/5)-\arccos(1/6)+\arccos(1/7)-\arccos(1/8)+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I brute force calculated the result until 150 terms, the result was -1.32457494 radians.

Does the answer tend to $-π/2$?

Comment: $a_n=\arccos(1/n)\to\pi/2\neq 0$... Isn't the series divergent?

Comment: Yeah, you might need to group the terms in pairs to make it converge.

Comment: If the sum of an even n7mber of terms goes to $-\pi/2,$ then the sum of an odd number of terms would go to $0.$ But we can show the sums $S_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\arccos(1/k)$ are positive and increasing.